# Go module for multiple packages, with new major number >1

Tags: go, module

I am trying to migrate an existing Go project to use modules but having difficulties working out the correct directory structure. The repo contains two regular packages (p1, p2) along with example programs to demonstrate how to use the packages. I am using Go 1.13.

The current layout is

```
<reponame>
   |
   +---  p1
   |     |
   |     +-- p1a.go
   |     +-- p1b.go
   |
   +---  p2
   |     |
   |     +-- p2a.go
   |     +-- p2b.go
   |
   +--  examples
         |
         +-- e1.go (which refers to packages p1 and p2)
```

The github repository is already public with a version tag > 1. I know I need a new major number, v5, so it looks like I need to move to having v5 somewhere in the path to the packages.

But should it be `<repo>/v5/p1` or `<repo>/p1/v5`? Where do go.mod files go? I suspect I need one to cover the two packages, and one for the example programs.

All the examples I can find for version > 1 seem to only have a single package in the module.

And importantly, how do I get the examples to compile and run? I've tried all kinds of permutations of a go.mod file for the examples but they all keep failing with an error like "no matching versions for query 'v5'" even with the "replace" directive to try to point at the local directories.

It looks like it is expecting a v5 version of code to be already published to github before I've done local testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Modules are about versioning. If p1, p2 and example are versioned *together* then put the go.mod at the repo level. This is probably the what you want.
2. Make sure the module declares itself properly, i.e. `module <repo>/v5` in the go.mod file.
3. You do *not* *need* the `v5` in the file system path. There are basically three ways: A `v5` folder containing the v5 stuff, a `v5` branch containing the v5 stuff or none of the two in which case your repo will be v5 only.
4. Make sure the import paths are correct. E.g. in package examples you must import p1 via `import "<repo>/v5/p1"`. (Same for p2 or even p1 importing p2, etc.)

Thats all.

`cd` into the example folder and `go build`: Go will look up the filesystem tree for a go.mod and will find it at the repo root. It thus knows that this package belongs to module `<repo>/v5` and thus where to find all packages from the module `<repo>/v5` and can import `<repo>/v5/p1` without the need for any replace directive. Like this you can work locally on the v5 without need to push to a remote repo.

(A common mistake is to not *declare* the module as v5: In the go.mod file you must have a line `module github.com/<user>/<repo>/v5`. If you falsely just write module `github.com/<user>/<repo>` then when compiling e.g. examples the compiler thinks "well, the `examples` package belongs to module `github.com/<user>/<repo>` and I should import `github.com/<user>/<repo>/v5/p1` so let's peek at github.com// to see what we find there..." and wont find anything and complain.)